# Can I call this distribution a power-law distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, graph-theory

I have some data about the number of nodes in thousands of networks, and I plotted them to understand what distribution it may follow. As the figure shows, I thought it might be a power-law distribution, so I used Gillespie's poweRlaw tool to estimate the $\alpha$, and the p-value is 0.109 in this case.

[image: My plot]

However, I am confused that my figure is quite different from typical power-law distribution, especially the "fat" tail that indicates some extreme values.

So does it follow a power-law distribution? If not, how can I describe this kind of distribution?

I am not good at math and this is the first time I ask a question here, I will be very appreciated for the help of this community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome to MSE.

As often, saying that a degree sequence fits a specific law distribution is open to debate. This will depends on the consequence you want to draw. In your case, given that the $p$-value is not great, and more importantly the absence of high values, in **my own opinion** I would say that it does not. Have you tried other distributions? I would test non-scale free laws, mainly the log-normal distribution, or maybe exponential.

Regarding Power-Law degree sequence, I **highly** recommend reading :

- The article [Scale-free networks are rare](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.03400), available on arxiv.
- This [webpage](https://www.quantamagazine.org/scant-evidence-of-power-laws-found-in-real-world-networks-20180215/) summarising the current dispute over power law sequences

> The fact is for years, network scientist have claimed that "real-world networks are typically obeys a power-law degree sequence". In this article, Broido and Clauset tested the omnipresence of scale-free structures by applying **statistical tools** to a large number of network data sets drawn from social, biological, technological, and informational sources. Their finding is that across domains, scale-free networks are in fact rare.

Maybe you could try to follow their approach to your specific data set?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did a compare with log-normal, exponential, and truncated power-law distribution using the Python powerlaw package, truncated power-law maybe the best among all. However, I don't quite understand what you mean by saying "the absence of high values", could you explain it in more detail? Thank you!